# access denied named pipes in WebAPI on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, named-pipes

to controll a windows service (and some other stuff) we use a WebAPI. For the communication between the API and the windows service I used NampedPipe. When I run the code in visual studio, everything works fine. After deploying the api to the IIS it get an IO exception `access denied`. Is this an configuration issue or is it impossible to access NamedPipes from the IIS API?

What could by a differnt approach? Ip connection?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**:

After some research and try and error I came to the conclusion: for NamedPipes to work both processes have to run under the same user.
So I assigned to both service and iis website the same user an gave it a try and it worked.

Is it safe to run a website on iis on a differnt user?

Comment: You could try register the port in URLACL. `netsh http add urlacl ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application get activated in IIS express When you debug application in development environment. In IIS express, your current login user are used to execute the application.

However, when you deploy the application in IIS, everything get executed by application pool identity and isolated in session 0.

So most of time, you can try to set app pool identity to local system.

Since Local system grant too much permission for an application, use a dedicated account to host your IIS application would be a good idea.

As long as you follow the least permission principle, use a different user for your website can be safe.